# Removing Redis Hash Key's field on LRU

Tags: hash, redis, lru

How can I set LRU on Redis which is not on instance level but on some particular.
Let's say a hash.
I am using hash-key as one cache bucket and field as key and value is value.
So it is like :
   Redis;s key-field-value = type-key-field     for me.

If it is not straight forward then I would like to use another DB Level LRU.
 ( One Redis instance have 16 DB, I would like to use DB 1 as LRU That means everything which goes in DB 1 will follows LRU, and which goes in DB-2,3... will not follow LRU ).

Answer (score 1):

I implemented it with Hash + Sorted Set.

in my case equivalent to Redis specification is :

Hash
key, field, value = type, key, value

Sorted Set :
key, score, value = type, lru_counter, key

( Takes the lowest range (if you want to remove 5 elements, zrange(type, 0, 4) ) which will give you least recently used 5 keys )

Hash will store actual cache.
And Sorted Set will store Just keys ( as members ) with scores. Every put and get in redis hash ( on any key ), will increment lru_counter ( an integer variable ) and put entry in sorted set with the same key ( type, lru_counter, key ) and lru_counter score.

Hence the recent put/get will have highest score ( lru_counter ) value in Sorted Set for the same key.

And when it comes to removal, I takes out the lowest scored members ( zrange, which is key for Hash ) and remove from both Sorted Set and Hash.